# How to create a "Concave/Convex Circle Illusion" in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, graphics

This semester, I am taking a Computer Graphics course at school, and our first assignment is to create a concave/convex illusion.

This is an example of what I am supposed to create:

[Concave/Convex Circle Illusion](http://www.psy.ritsumei.ac.jp/~akitaoka/craterillusion02.jpg)

[image]

I've tried to work this problem out myself, however I keep getting stuck. I know how to create the gray background, and I know how to create a circle. What I dont know how to do is to make the circle look like the picture. I know how to fill it with a solid color, I just dont know how to fill it with multiple colors and fade it like in the picture.

So here is my C++ code which we run in Visual Studio 15.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>

const double p = 3.14159/180;

void circle(float r){
     glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
     glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
     for (int i=100; i <= 460; i++){
         double degree = p*i;
         double x = cos(degree) * r;
         double y = sin(degree) * r;
         glVertex2d(x,y);
     }
     glEnd();
}

/*

//This circle function was my attempt at creating the illusion shown in the picture above.
//I tried to break up the circle into separate pieces and make them each a different color,
//but unfortunately it didnt come out like the picture above.

void circle (float radius){
     glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0); // black
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(21,21);
        glVertex2i(25,19);
        glVertex2i(28,17);
        glVertex2i(32,16);
        glVertex2i(36,17);
        glVertex2i(40,19);
        glVertex2i(43,21);
     glEnd();
     glColor3f(0.329412,0.329412,0.329412);  // dim grey
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(21,21);
        glVertex2i(19,25);
        glVertex2i(17,30);
        glVertex2i(48,30);
        glVertex2i(46,25);
        glVertex2i(43,21);
     glEnd();
     glColor3f(0.752941,0.752941,0.752941);  // grey
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(17,30);
        glVertex2i(16,35);
        glVertex2i(15,40);
        glVertex2i(50,40);
        glVertex2i(49,35);
        glVertex2i(48,30);
     glEnd();
     glColor3f(0.650024,0.650024,0.650024);  // light grey
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(15,40);
        glVertex2i(16,45);
        glVertex2i(17,50);
        glVertex2i(48,50);
        glVertex2i(49,45);
        glVertex2i(50,40);
     glEnd();
     glColor3f(0.8,0.8,0.8);  //  very light grey
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(17,50);
        glVertex2i(20,55);
        glVertex2i(45,55);
        glVertex2i(48,50);
     glEnd();
     glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);  // white
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2i(20,55);
        glVertex2i(23,58);
        glVertex2i(25,60);
        glVertex2i(28,62);
        glVertex2i(32,63);
        glVertex2i(36,62);
        glVertex2i(40,60);
        glVertex2i(43,58);
        glVertex2i(45,55);
     glEnd();
}

*/


void display(void){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     glColor3f(0.658824,0.658824,0.658824);
     glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Creates the gray background
        glVertex2i(10,10);
        glVertex2i(390, 10);
        glVertex2i(390,290);
        glVertex2i(10,290);
     glEnd();
     circle(30);
     glFlush();
}



void main(int argc, char** argv){
     glutInit(&argc, argv);
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
     glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
     glutInitWindowPosition(200,100);
     glutCreateWindow("Project 1");
     glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
     glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
     glLoadIdentity();
     gluOrtho2D(0.0,400.0,0.0,300.0);
     glutDisplayFunc(display);
     glutMainLoop();
}
```

So Ive got the majority of the code down, I just cant figure out the coloring of the circle.

Any advice/help that can make the outcome of my code look like the example picture above would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since several years.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

But, the effect of the picture is achieved by a simple gray color gradient. The background is gray and inside the circle is a linear color gradient from white to black.

[`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glClear.xml), clear the framebuffer by the color which is set by [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml).
Set a gray clear color to create a gray background:

```
glClearColor( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f );
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

To create a color gradient, you have to set the color attribute by [`glColor3d`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml), before you set the vertex coordinate by [`glVertex2d`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml). The color is interpolated between the vertices. Use the [primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` to create a filled polygon:

```
const double p = 3.14159/180;

void circle(float r, bool flip ){

     glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
     glColor3d( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
     glVertex2d( 0.0, 0.0 );
     for (int i=0; i <= 360; i++)
     {
         double degree = p*i;
         double c = cos( degree );
         double s = sin( degree );

         double col = s * 0.5 + 0.5;
         if ( flip )
           col = 1.0 - col;
         glColor3d( col, col, col );
         glVertex2d( c*r, s*r );
     }
     glEnd();
}
```

The `draw` function may look like this:

```
void display(void){
     glClearColor( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f );
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
     glLoadIdentity();

     for ( int x = 0; x < 2; ++ x )
     {
       for ( int y = 0; y < 2; ++ y)
       {
           glPushMatrix();
           glTranslated( 120.0 + 160.0*x, 100.0+100*y, 0.0f );
           circle(30, x > 0);
           glPopMatrix();
       }
     }

     glFlush();
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I also have another question: How could I change the code such that only one circle appears, or two, etc. I was playing around with the code, and I kept getting circles that were cut off or they wouldnt appear.

Comment: @Joseph Since the  call of `circle` is in a nested loop, you get 4 circles. The center point of the circle is defined by `glTranslated`. If you want 1 circle, in the center of the screen, then delete the 2 `for`-loops and use  `glTranslated(200.0, 150, 0.0f );` for the translation. (200, 150) is the center, because of `glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);` and `gluOrtho2D(0.0,400.0,0.0,300.0);`.